# Launch4J exe doesn't run if drag and drop files on it

Tags: java, file, exe, shortcut, launch4j

I created an EXE for my Java program using **Launch4J**.

The program needs a file/folder to be **drag and dropped on the EXE** in order to start processing it.

It all works if I launch the EXE from command line passing the path of the file as argument, or if I create a shortcut in Windows to the EXE and drag and drop a file on the shortcut.

Otherwise, **if I drop the file directly on the EXE**, the program seems not to even open.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: *"if I drop the file directly on the EXE"*  Do you mean the open application or the shortcut that launches it?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Thanks, this solved the same problem here.